# Delete pattern matching regex from sed capture group

Tags: bash, regex, sed

I'm trying to remove all instances of '_(one number)' from certain strings in a file. So **tig00000003_1** should become **tig00000003** This is what my test file looks like:

```
##sequence-region tig00000001_732 1 630
tig00000003_1 Name=tig00000003_1;
```

I've tried
`sed -E 's/(tig[0-9]{8}\_[0-9]{1})/ \1(tig[0-9]{8}) /' my_test.txt` , which gives:

```
##sequence-region  tig00000001_7(tig[0-9]{8}) 32 1 630
 tig00000003_1(tig[0-9]{8}) Name=tig00000003_1;
```

and this is what I want:

```
##sequence-region tig00000001_732 1 630
tig00000003 Name=tig00000003;
```

how can I remove the matched pattern in the capture group,or alternately only keep the match within the capture group?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply replace the '_(one number)' with nothing on any lines that are
not comments like so:

```
sed '/^[^#]/ s/\_[0-9]//g' your_file
```

The way it works is as follows:

- Lines not matching comments are identified as those that start with (`^`)
  any non # symbol (`[^#]`)
- Then on those lines substitute any underscore + digit (`_[0-9]`) with
  nothing `(//)` every time that pattern is found on the line (`g`)

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close. Use capturing parentheses around the "tig" number

```bsh
sed -E '/^#/n; s/(tig[0-9]{8})\_[0-9]/\1/g' my_test.txt
# ...............^^^^^^^^^^^^^........^^
```